# want to disable selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php

I want to disable the checkboxes selected by user1 so that if another user logins the page he should not able to make any changes on the selectedcheckboxes.It is somewhat like restaurant table booking system

```
<?php 
 $st = "select * from seat where hotel='$test'";
 $q= mysqli_query($conn,$st);
 $tester = mysqli_fetch_array($q);
 $tab = $tester['two'];
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="bookbtn" value="Book Your table">
<div id="mask2"style="float:left;width:20%;">
    <?php $i=1;
      while ($i<=$tab) 
      {?>
        <div class="TWO">
          <div class="check"style="height:40px;width:120px;">
            <div class="seconda">
            </div>
            <div class="secondb">
              <input type ="checkbox"name="checky[]"
              style="width:30px;height:30px;"
              value="<?php echo "two".$i;?>"
              <?php if (in_array("two".$i, $expcheck)) {?>
               checked="checked"<?php }else {echo "none";}?>>
         </div>
            <div class="secondc">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: *I want to disable the checkboxes selected by user1*, **so disable it, What's the problem?**

Answer (score 0):

After you have determined that it has been selected:

```
document.getElementByID('yourcheckboxID').setAttribute("disabled", "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
just written disabled and it works

<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="bookbtn" value="Book Your table">
<div id="mask2"style="float:left;width:20%;">
    <?php $i=1;
      while ($i<=$tab) 
      {?>
        <div class="TWO">
          <div class="check"style="height:40px;width:120px;">
            <div class="seconda">
            </div>
            <div class="secondb">
              <input type ="checkbox"name="checky[]"
              style="width:30px;height:30px;"
              value="<?php echo "two".$i;?>"
              <?php if (in_array("two".$i, $expcheck)) {?>
               checked="checked"<?php }else {echo "none";}?>disabled>
         </div>
            <div class="secondc">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```